# Is using spark.sql.functions considered functional programming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming, bigdata

I am wondering exactly what would be considered functional programming in the case of using scala and spark. If I am using functions from the spark.sql.functions library and working with immutable data along with separating code out into different functions which have no other side effects would that be considered functional programming?

For example is there a different way I should approach finding the number of sales made per year or would the below be satisfactory

```
def salesPerYear(sales: Dataset[Sale]): Dataset[Row] =
    sales.groupBy("Year").count()
```

Comment: I would say that the functional paradigm requires that a program is built only from pure functions which for a given input always return the same output i.e. the result can be cached and/or reused on different places for example. Here your function seems to be pure. That does not mean that all the environment is pure or your function cannot be improved. I am still learning scala (and FP), so I will not try to write abstract code here, but you just implement  A.groupBy(B).count() pattern so I am curious if someone can make an abstract pattern from that.